# SmtpClient: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, email, gmail, smtpclient

While working with Email sending in C#.NET in visual studio 2008 i got the below error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.53.108:25

But the same code was working fine in some other PC but when i am testing today it gives me error in `Send()` method... Also my network connection is good where i am testing the email code..

Below is my email code

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUserName@gmail.com",
                                                            "MyPassword");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

What could be the reasons for such error..???

Comment: Maybe you exceeded the limit of sending mails from the account and operations might have been temporarily suspended for the account, did you try with another account ?

Comment: This is the first time i am testing this today but i dont think because of such reason there could be problem also i have send 5 mail previously in 1 day..... I have not tried with other account... but i will try that...

Comment: i have tried with other account also but did not work and same error occurs...

Comment: Why is the port shown as 25 are you setting it explicitly ? its a different port for SSL, if you are specifying any port just remove that

Comment: I think you should try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513412/676508

This solution saved my world.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following code works for me.  Your code was giving me errors, I believe it was due to not setting the port to 587.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1250771.aspx/4/10

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(address, password);
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me due to my company security wifi. Once I changed to open wifi, the problem was solved automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I was facing the same issue and my issue was resolved by changing my internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

This was a firewall issue, adding a rule to bypass your IP / IP of application server resolves this and is able to connect to the SMTP server.