# Can't auth to Gmail smtp via MailMessage & smtpClient

Tags: c#, gmail, smtpclient

I cannot figure out for the life of my why this isn't working

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPasswordHere"),
    EnableSsl = true,
    Timeout = 10000
};


smtp.Send(mail);
```

I get:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I just specified EnableSsl to true so that shouldn't be the issue in terms of secure connection.

I'm running this from localhost. And yes, my username and password I'm entering to auth (my gmail account credentials) is 100% right.

Comment: Have you declared it in web.config?

Comment: no, for now just hard coding it.  Should not matter for testing, web.config or not.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict please check answers and provide an accepted one, if there is one.

Answer (score 41):

I know this is an old topic, BUT... Google has changed something on their security settings.

Was struggling with all the answers until I checked my email with a mail from Google stating that "we've recently blocked a sign-in attempt on your Google account".

That led me to this page:
[Google Account Security](https://www.google.com/settings/security)

Under the "Access for less secure apps" section, you can enable access to your account from other devices/applications... like your C# application.

Note, there is no longer an "application specific" section.

Hope this helps someone... I just lost 30 minutes of my life...

Comment: this answer should get more votes.. sometimes we should try less voted answers too.. I tried all articles and really gave up after I tried solution marked as answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail  I mean I had no idea what am doing wrong.. Thanks Tiny.. your solution worked for me..

Comment: This really helped me. I don't understand why this information isn't easier to find.

Comment: So what do I need to change in my code if I don't want to allow "less secure apps" in my gmail account?

Comment: if you use your own domain, you need to use https://admin.google.com/ to set *2-step-verification* or allowing *less secure apps*

Comment: I turned on allowing less secure app access and still having intermittent issues. I don't follow what this reply is suggesting to do exactly.

Answer (score 23):

If login info is 100% right, you need to set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` **first** and then set the credentials you want to use `Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPasswordHere")`.

If you set the credentials first, when you set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` this will make the `Credentials` property to `null`.

This is wired, but it happened to me.

Debug your code and check if the `Credentials` property is null before you call `smtp.Send(message);`. If so, then try inverting the order. It seems you have it in the right order, but if it's null, don't use the inline initialization.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** If you are using two-step verification, be sure you are using an [App Specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: Indeed this really works. Had same problem and this fixed mine out.

Comment: I spent 3 hours on this today... can't believe this fixed it.

Comment: OMG... spent half of the day trying nearly everything. THANKS for the answer!

Comment: this did not work for me but i did consider it.. plz try http://stackoverflow.com/a/25414099/2649883 if still facing problem

Comment: incredible but in this order is work correctly  

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();  

**smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;**  

smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderAddress,senderPassword);  
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;  
smtpClient.Host = host;  
smtpClient.Port = port;  
smtpClient.EnableSsl = useSsl;  
return smtpClient;

Answer (score 11):

It looks like Gmail requires Application-specific password(not your main password).

Please, look into this: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1173270

I had the same problem recently.

Comment: Much thx, that did the trick for me.  Using the code base from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/489594/271992), following [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513412/271992) along with my application generated [2-step verification](http://www.google.com/2step) Google password (*not* my regular Gmail password), I was able to send email from a C# test client.  I was doing development/testing on my local desktop using my personal Gmail account and forgot I had enabled Gmail's [2-step verification](http://www.google.com/2step)...so that is 2 hours of my life I'll never get back! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25414099/2649883 works fine. there is no application specific section in gmail anymore

Answer (score 3):

This worked just fine for me

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myid@gmail.com", "mypassword"),
        EnableSsl = true,
        Timeout = 10000
    };

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.Body = "hello there";
    message.Subject = "hi!!";
    message.To.Add("myid@gmail.com");
    message.From = new MailAddress("myid@gmail.com");
    smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem before and fixed it by following these steps:

1. Go to "***My Account***" settings.
2. Click "***Sign-in & Security***" category.
3. Scroll down to "***Connected apps & sites***" section.
4. turn off the "***Allow less secure apps***" option.

I just turned this option off and my code ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution required 2 "steps":

- set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` first, then set the credentials I want to use `Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPasswordHere")`.  Setting the credentials first, when I set `UseDefaultCredentials = false` will make the Credentials property `null`.
- Allow less secure apps on my Google profile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mailSettings>
            <smtp from="youremail@gmail.com">
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="yourpassword" port="587" userName="username"/>
            </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Edit: try adding this line `smtp.Credentials = Credentials` after this

`Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPasswordHere"),`

Comment: yea I know you can do this but this doesn't explain why the hard coded magic strings of mine above (only for testing) isn't working.

Comment: why?  I already set that in the object initializer for smtpClient Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPasswordHere")

Answer (score 0):

Have a callback as follows. Tell `System.Net` to ignore the error!

Add this before call to `Send()`

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
    { return true; };

smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Well don't eat then... handle the enum. Do tell us what you got.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue accessing smtp.gmail.com from an ASP.NET application running on Amazon AWS hosting. It turned out that my configuration was right - it was also working fine from another computer - but gmail would deny my login attempt, because I try logging in from an unusual location. 
I logged on to gmail over the web interface (www.gmail.com), and had to answer a captcha. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the domain-owner for our gmail-account had disabled both "Access for less secure apps" and two step authentication. There was no way to enable it, I couldn't even see the setting. So I tested with my personal account instead, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just follow this for C# WPF Application:

```
       private void SendByGmail(string subject, string body, string recepientEmail, string MailMsgFrom, string MailMsgPass)
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(MailMsgFrom);
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = body;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
                mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Timeout = 200000;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = MailMsgFrom;
                NetworkCred.Password = MailMsgPass;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);

            }
        }
```

After that you should get like this Error

```
smtpException   {"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"}   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
```

To Solve this problem, at first login your email account to your google account in web browser. Then just follow this link [Google Account Activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?pli=1). Then you'll get recent Devices & activity by your account. If show block your current activity from your current device. Just Unblock this. Then try again to send email. 
 Thanks