# The SMTP server does not support authentication. When using email verification with identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is my first time doing email verification,i followed a tutorial which used papercut and an example email,but i wanted to try do this with an actual gmail but i get the following error:**The SMTP server does not support authentication. When using email verification with identit**

i assume there something wrong with my json file

```
"Email": {
    "Server": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "SenderName": "LoveLetter",
    "SenderEmail": "crunchgymemailbot@gmail.com",
    "Account": "emailbot3123***@gmail.com",
    "Password": "mypassword"
  },"
```

here is  a part of my register code

```
  if (result.Succeeded)  {
        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

            var link = Url.Action(nameof(VerifyEmail), "Home", new { userId = user.Id, code }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToString());

          code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

          await _emailService.SendAsync(model.Email, "email verify", $"<a href=\"{link}\">Verify Email</a>", true);

          return RedirectToAction("EmailVerification");
                    }
```

and my startup.cs

```
var mailKitOptions = Configuration.GetSection("Email").Get<MailKitOptions>();
            services.AddMailKit(config => config.UseMailKit(mailKitOptions));
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/13504988?hl=en

Comment: If the linked question doesn't answer yours, please tag me in a comment (@john) and let me know why not, and I'll reopen your question.

Comment: @John completely different problem

Comment: Can you advise what have you tried to do to solve this so far? [This option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624587/3181933) definitely doesn't make a difference?

Comment: @John i encountered  that problem in a different project it was because of the gmail security settings,this problem has a different error and im sure its something wrong with my code and i wondered if someone could give me an example code