# Error when trying to send mails using smtp

Tags: c#, smtp

I have got the following error message when i tried to sent message using smtp.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 67.69.240.69:25
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 67.69.240.69:25
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Handler.BLL.cSendMail.SendMail(String p_strFrom, String p_strDisplayName, String p_strTo, String p_strSubject, String p_strMessage, String strFileName)
[ staffID:,21/08/2013 9:49:34 AM ]: status code : GeneralFailure
```

code

```
   public bool SendMail(string p_strFrom, string p_strDisplayName, string p_strTo, string p_strSubject, string p_strMessage , string strFileName)
 {
     try
     {
         p_strDisplayName = _DisplayName;
         string smtpserver = _SmtpServer;
         SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
         MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
         MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(_From,_DisplayName);
         smtpClient.Host = _SmtpServer;
         smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(_Port);
         string strAuth_UserName = _UserName;
         string strAuth_Password = _Password;
         if (strAuth_UserName != null)
         {
             System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strAuth_UserName, strAuth_Password);
             smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
             if (_SSL)
             {
                 smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
             }
             smtpClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
         }
         message.From = fromAddress;

         message.Subject = p_strSubject;
         message.IsBodyHtml = true;
         message.Body = p_strMessage;
         message.To.Add(p_strTo);
         try
         {
             smtpClient.Send(message);
             Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending first try success", "");
         }
          catch (Exception ee)
         {
             Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending first try Failed : " + ee.ToString(), "");
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.WriteLog("smtpClient mail sending overall failed : " + ex.ToString());  
         return false;
     }
 }
```

when 3 or more mail sending only one or two fails

Comment: How about pasting your code

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with your **port setting**

Try setting your `Port to 587` instead of `port 25` ,also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102687/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond)

Comment: I am using smtp10.on.aibn.com server.Is it possible to set 587?

Answer (score 1):

Once i was fell into the same error and found that port 25 was blocked by the antivirus which i have installed in system. I just disabled it.
If your smtp is hosted over other machine or it is third party hosting than you have to clarify that whether the port 25 is unblock or not.