# Sending email via GMail: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am using [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp) and [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102687/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond) to create simple email sending Application on c# console App. But I am getting error when sent email on gmail ...

> {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX"}

Here is my Code :

```
class Program
    {
        private static string to = "XXX@gmail.com";
        private static string from = "XXX@gmail.com";
        private static string subject="07/10/14";
        private static string body;
        private static string address = "XXX@gmail.com";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials =
                 new System.Net.NetworkCredential(address, "YYYYY");
            smtp.Send(mail);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


}
```

My App.Config File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="XXX@gmail.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="false"
        userName="XXX@gmail.com"
           password="YYYYY"
        host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>

  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I have read similar post ..Some suggest convert url into stream ..I did not get it ..Some says problem might be in internet connection ..other says set smtp server to 587 ..I have applied all changes ..still it shows same error

Please Suggest

Comment: Did you try the following? `mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com"));`

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue?

Comment: I added mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com")); ...still not working ...

Comment: @DGibbs  It is not  on my system ...Might be on company gateway ..what can be done in that case

Comment: my last idea is to try port 465 when using ssl. also that might be interesting: [Sending mail from a printer, scanner or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Comment: I have check that it might be firewall ..I m working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved this problem ...

**Just use your Hosting Company Smtp and Port ..not gmail or other one..If you are sending from a hosting company ....Consult your IT Desk for providing your company smtp address and port ..I did that..that solved the Issue**

This is My Working Code ..**it is also sending to gmail by company SMTP**

```
class Program
    {
        private static string to = "XXXXr@youHostingComapny.com";
        private static string from = "YYYYY@youHostingComapny.com";
        private static string subject = "test Mail sent By Code";
        private static string body = "Mail sent By Code";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                MailMessage mail = null;

                using (mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(from), new MailAddress(to)))
                {

                    mail.Subject = subject;
                    mail.Body = body;
                    mail.To.Add("ZZZZZZZZ@gmail.com");

                    SmtpClient smtpMail = null;
                    using (smtpMail = new SmtpClient("HostingComapny smtp Address"))
                    {
                        smtpMail.Port = Hosting Company Port No.;
                        smtpMail.EnableSsl = false;
                        smtpMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youruserName", "yourPassword");

                        smtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        // and then send the mail
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
             X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    { return true; };
                        smtpMail.Send(mail);
                        Console.WriteLine("sent");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: You should be able to mark this as the accepted answer (there's usually a timelimit before you can do that) which is better than changing the question to "Solved.."