# Connection attempt failed error while sending mail to the Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

In my project, I have implemented a `Forgot password` functionality where users enters his/her Email-Id ID and submits the button. Then he will receive his ID and password details on the Registered email id.

This all functionality is working fine on my local server. But when I integrated this to server, it gives me error as

> *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.68.109:587*

I also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102687/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond) but it did not helped me out and was getting the same error.

Here is my `Send Mail` Code:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username,password FROM tbl_User Where email= '" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
                Msg.Subject = "Password Details";
                Msg.Body = "Hi, <br/>Your login details are<br/><br/>Your Username is: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"] + "<br/><br/>Your Password is: " + Decrypt(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString()) + "<br/><br/>";
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                // your remote SMTP server IP.
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mygmailid", "**********");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                Msg = null;
                //lbltxt.Text = "Your Password Details Sent to your mail";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Your Password Details Sent to your mail');window.location ='Login.aspx';", true);
                // Clear the textbox valuess
                txtEmail.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Email Id you entered does not exist');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what might be the issue.

**STACK TRACE ERROR:-**

> *
>   Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'
>   Source Error: 
>   Line 63:                         smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mygmailid", "************");
>   Line 64:                         smtp.EnableSsl = true;
>   Line 65:                         smtp.Send(Msg);
>   Line 66:                         Msg = null;
>   Line 67:                         //lbltxt.Text = "Your Password Details Sent to your mail";
>   Source File: d:\RBLBank\NGOManagement-CSR\CSRProject\ForgotPassword.aspx.cs    Line: 65 
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com']
>      System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) +7895034
>      System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +7895462
>      System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +36
>      System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +2868427
>      System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +286
>      System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1553
>   [SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
>      System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +2187943
>      CSRProject.ForgotPassword.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\RBLBank\NGOManagement-CSR\CSRProject\ForgotPassword.aspx.cs:65
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean >includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
>   *

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Ok, let me try with that.

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Tried that port, still getting the same error. Not working

Comment: Ok so Try to set some extra timeout. For example: smtp.TimeOut = int.max;. Give it few minutes and check if the e-mail was sent

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Can you tell me how to set the `timeout` ?

Comment: I told You - smtp class have property called TimeOut. After this: SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); Paste this: smtp.TimeOut = 99999;

Comment: And I also suggest to use Try Catch block within send method

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Yes let me to that and try

Comment: `smtp.TimeOut = 99999;` is giving me error as ` CS1061: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' does not contain a definition for 'TimeOut' and no extension method 'TimeOut' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Timeout* There shouldn't be capital o - my mistake.

Comment: Not working, still getting the same error..!

Comment: Ok let me think a little bit. btw. Try this with both Ports(465, 587) and You can set Timeout to 999999 to be sure it's not the problem.

Comment: Please paste us full exception - with stack trace. It will help to find a problem/

Comment: And check if Your firewall/antivirus doesn't block 465/587 ports.

Comment: Ok, wait. Let me check again

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Actually the firewall was blocking the port for `587`. I have asked the server team to enable the port. Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Actually i sould start with this firewall suggestion :)

Comment: aahhh yes, actually i would only had checked it first.. :P