# Unable to send hotmail from C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, hotmail

Here is my code:

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("MAIL@hotmail.com");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("MAIL@hotmail.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Message du siute as-quebec.net de: " + EmailToSend.Email;
message.Body = EmailToSend.Message;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MAIL@hotmail.com", "PASSWORD");
client.Send(message);
```

I have this error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : 'Failure sending mail.'

> ExtendedSocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or an established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Some ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587) { EnableSsl = true };`

Comment: I have the same error with your modification...

Comment: Check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7102687/7067740)

Comment: Which version of Windows and .NET do you have, exact build numbers please?

Comment: This sounds like it is first and foremost a networking issue, not a programming one. Does a Mail Client running on the same computer, with the same account work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-8.0), if one specifies the incorrect value for SMTP server name (ie: [SmtpClient.Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.host?view=net-8.0)), one receives the following error message:

> **System.Net.Mail.SmtpException**: 'Failure sending mail.'
>
> **WebException**: Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> **SocketException**: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

---

According to [POP, IMAP, and SMTP settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353):

**SMTP Settings**

[image]

---

Also, ensure that you call *Dispose* for anything that has a *Dispose* method. The easiest way to do this, is with a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) (or [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration)).

Try the following:

```
private void SendEmailOutlook(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string subject, string messageText, bool isHtmlMessage, string username, string password)
{
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587) { DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, EnableSsl = true, UseDefaultCredentials = false })
    {
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(toAddress);

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to) { IsBodyHtml = isHtmlMessage })
        {
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = messageText;

            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.From = "mail@hotmail.com";
message.To = "mail@hotmail.com";
message.Subject = $"New mail from {message.From}";
message.Body = "something";
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    var msg = new MailMessage
    {
        Body = message.Body,
        Subject = message.Subject,
        From = new MailAddress(message.From)
    };
    msg.To.Add(message.To);
    smtp.Host = "email.active24.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@hotmail.com", password);
    smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

You just need Host and Port from your provider

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).